# Electron forge: github publisher doesn't create any release

Tags: electron, electron-forge, publisher

I created an electron app using `yarn create electron-app my-app` which I am hosting on github (https://github.com/amblafont/essai-electron). I updated `package.json` and `forge.config.js` to add the github publisher. But it doesn't create any new github release.

`yarn run publish` doesn't throw any error (see the log below), but it doesn't create any release on github. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ electron-forge publish
✔ Checking your system
✔ Loading configuration
✔ Resolving publish targets
  › Publishing to the following targets: github
✔ Running make command
  ✔ Loading configuration
  ✔ Resolving make targets
    › Making for the following targets: zip
  ✔ Running package command
    ✔ Preparing to package application
    ✔ Running packaging hooks
      ✔ Running generateAssets hook
      ✔ Running prePackage hook
    ✔ Packaging application
      ✔ Packaging for x64 on linux [1s]
    ✔ Running postPackage hook
  ✔ Running preMake hook
  ✔ Making distributables
    ✔ Making a zip distributable for linux/x64 [9s]
  ✔ Running postMake hook
    › Artifacts available at: ***/my-app/out/make
✔ Publishing distributables
  ✔ [publisher-github] Running the publish command
    › Uploading distributable (1/1 to v1.0.0)
```

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

By default, electron-forge publishes them in draft status.

Go to your releases page in your repository. You can see the releases which are in draft status. You need to change the status from draft to release by clicking on the edit icon and then clicking on the publish button which will make the release publicly available.

Comment: Where is that "publish button" available? Can't see that option after marking it as Prerelease

Comment: Click the release on the repo page(under the About section on the right side).